# Do I have to manually remove orphaned commits

Tags: git, github

I am working on a PR.
I used `git rebase -i HEAD~2` on my branch, and changed the `n-1`th commit message. Then I force pushed upstream. This is all okay since nobody is using my commits.

But I read that there will be an orphaned commit. What does that mean? Do I have to remove it manually in git or in GitHub? Or is it taken care by the maintainer?

Comment: Short answer is no. The garbage collector covers this automatically. (see [git gc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc))